# How to sync a pull request in Github

Tags: git, github

I made a pull request in a branch XXX, before the pull request has been accepted, some other PR were merged. So my own PR was outdated. Then I fetch the main repository and merged it to my master. Then I merge the master in my branch XXX.

But this causes issues to my team mates, they are unable to rebase.

So what can we do now, and what should I have done ?

Comment: There are a few things in this question that are unclear:

1. "I made a pull request in a branch XXX". So by this, you mean you created branch XXX and then sent a pull request to merge XXX to master, correct?
2. "Then I fetch the main repository and merged it to my master." This is confusing. Do you mean that you fetched master from the main repository and merged it into master in your local checkout?
3. "But this causes issues to my team mates, they are unable to rebase." What do you mean by that?

Comment: 1) Correct
2) I ran these commands
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git checkout XXX
git merge master

3) They are issuing errors where using rebase. I don't have more info about it right now

Comment: I may be missing something, but it doesn't sound to me like any of the commands you ran could possibly affect anyone else on your team. (You only modified branch XXX, and you didn't even push your changes anywhere?) It's likely that the problems your teammates are experiencing are unrelated to anything you mentioned here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rebase your PR with the upstream `git rebase upstream/master`.

You may need to do `git remote add upstream <url-to-upstream>` & `git fetch upstream master` before rebase.

After rebasing your branch, you'll need to force push it, do `git push -f` to achieve this.

Don't pull the changes from upstream.
Hope this helps!

Comment: The question was how to do this on GitHub (not manually with Git command line). BitBucket has a "sync" button for this.

Comment: Hi @arni, It's your presumption that OP is fixated on GitHub only. The question says "So what can we do now, and what should I have done?", I think this answer solves that problem. 

If you are looking for a GitHub specific solution, I am not aware of a method to remove a merge commit on GitHub UI but I don't use the UI enough, so please post a separate answer, I cannot help with the same unfortunately.

Comment: By the time, I've learnt to master git and use it like a third arm. I'm pretty sure back in 2014, I was already using command line tools.

Guess your solution is correct. The pattern I'm trying to describe seems horrible though

. Note that it could also be `origin` if we were not using forks. And I don't necessarily need to name it `upstream` even if it's best practice when working with forking pattern.

Comment: You can also pull the changes from upstream if your pull is configured to rebase only :)